# Getting a 'No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111' while using vladmihalcea JsonBinaryType

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jsonb

I found some similar questions but none that seem to match exactly my situation.  I am currently getting a 'No Dialect Mapping for JDBC Type: 1111', specifically for trying to map a jsonb type.  I have been trying to use the vladmihalcea library which I believe is meant to provide the mapping but it would appear that I am implementing it incorrectly.  Specifically I am consuming a kafka message that conforms to my entity type with an unknown object type that fills the jsonobject field.  For example:

MyEntity = {"field1":"stuff", "field2":"otherstuff", "jsonobject":"{could be anything here}"}

After being consumed the message object is then persisted to my db, super simple, at least in concept.

Here is my entity (minus the irrelevant fields, I know the issue is the annotated field as the system works when I remove the annotation, but it simply stores the object as a string rather than jsonb in my h2).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_Table")
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class MyEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long my_id;
    ...
    
    @Type(type="jsonb")
    private String jsonobject;
```

Below is my application.properties, shouldn't affect this I don't think but just in case.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Lastly, this is my repo.  Again it's a standard Crud so I don't expect it to affect anything but just in case.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>{
    
    

}
```

Comment: What h2 database version do you use?

Comment: @SternK I don't set a specific version in my pom but it would appear the jar that has been added is 1.4.200.